# Selecting information about tables in general - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Here are two cases I've run into recently:

1. Querying the set of tables for those that have more than 0 rows but less than 50 rows.
2. Querying all tables to find which has a column named a certain value.

Are either of these possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a table with a specific column name:

```
select * from all_tab_columns where column_name = '<colname in upper case>';
```

An estimate of the number of rows in a table can be found:

```
select table_name, num_rows from all_tables where num_rows between 1 and 49;
```

This will be close if your statistics are up to date. If not, you need to create a `pl/sql` process to loop through the tables and perform a `count(*)` on them.

EDIT: Have found an Ask Tom article on the number of rows query: [Finding the number of rows in each table by a single sql](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1660875645686).